# How to parse JSON list or object in C#

Tags: c#

I have one JSON like:

In success response it is like:

```
{
  statusCode: "200",
  status: "Success",
  data: [
    {
      empName: "Prashant",
      empCode: 001
    },
    {
      empName: "Jack",
      empCode: 002
    }
  ]
}
```

and In error response or if there is an exception while processing a request like:

```
{
  statusCode: "400",
  status: "Fail",
  data: {
    empId: "This field is mandatory"
  }
}
```

How I can parse the response in both case? Now I am getting an exception while parsing the JSON.

The C# Class I used to parse the response is:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public int empCode { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> data { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

The exception details:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Can you share the error which you are facing?

Comment: I believe you should check status code and deserialize it to different object.

Comment: yes give me 1 min

Comment: @AccessDenied yes but while parsing the Json its throwing an error so unable to get the value of status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects are not fixed and data must be configurable then Newtonsoft.json has one feature that to be use here and that is `[JsonExtensionData]`. [Read more](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/10/14/json-net-5-0-release-7-immutable-collections)

> Extension data is now written when an object is serialized. Reading and writing extension data makes it possible to automatically round-trip all JSON without adding every property to the .NET type you’re deserializing to. Only declare the properties you’re interested in and let extension data do the rest.

So in your case your `Response` class will be

```
public class Response
{
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> data;
}
```

All your data in `data` key will be collected in `[JsonExtensionData]` property.

You need to perform operations on  `[JsonExtensionData]` property to get your key/value pair. like

```
public class Employee
{
    public string empId { get; set; }
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public int empCode { get; set; }
}
```

And you can perform opration like

```
var json = "Your response";

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var statusCode = jObject["statusCode"];

var status = jObject["status"];

var data = jObject["data"];

if (data.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    var arrayData = data.ToObject<List<Employee>>();
}
else
if (data.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    var objData = data.ToObject<Employee>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your normal response maps directly to classes you provided. And this is deserialized without any problem.

The problem emerges, when you try deserialize your error resopnse. It specifies `empId` which is not present in any of your classes. That is generating exception.

Also, in your normal response, you have list in `data` (indicated by square brackets `[` and `]`), in second, you don't have a list. This is also inconsistent and is causing exception.

In order to make it work, you have to modify your error response:

1) change `empId` to `empName` or add `empId` in your `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string empId { get; set; }
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public int empCode { get; set; }
}
```

2) alter `data` field in JSON, so it will be an array:

```
{
    statusCode: ""400"",
    status: ""Fail"",
    data: [{
        empId: ""This field is mandatory""
    }]
}
```

Finally, deserialize it with:

```
var normalObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(normalJson);
var errorObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(errorJson);
```

**UPDATE**

If you want `statusCode` only, make the type of `data` in `Response` class `object`, so it won't throw exception while parsing:

```
public class Response
{
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }
}
```

To get `statusCode` directly, use:

```
var statusCode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(normalJson).statusCode;
statusCode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(errorJson).statusCode;
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I have tried but while parsing the list of employee its throws an exception

Comment: The code I used to get the List is:object response = await ApiResponse.GetEmployee(empId);
Response resp = (Response)response;
List<Employee> list = (List<Employee)resp;

Comment: You need to add `public string empId { get; set; }` in your `Employee` class as I mentioned.

Comment: But that EmpId feild is dynamic for ex. The key is not fixed

Comment: @PrashantPimpale It must be known, because you must to specify field of the same name. Alternatively, you could do some string manipulation to replace it with known name.

Comment: Yes that is where I am facing difficulties as I very well know how JSON parse works but this is what I have

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Look at update section, it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json [https://www.newtonsoft.com/json]
When you install Newtonsoft.Json from NugetLibrary you can use code below,

```
String json = "{statusCode: \"200\",status: \"Success\",data: [{empName: \"Prashant\",empCode: 001},{empName: \"Jack\",empCode: 002}]}";
Response resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(variableHoldingJsonString);
```

where `T` is the type of the object/list you want the main to be.

This will give the desired result.

However there is a lot of help out there already.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the Newtonsoft package from NuGet. It works really well.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Response);
```

T is the object of choice (you can special paste a JSON string to create a class if you have the web development kit active in VS2017).

Answer (score 1):

The class structure has to match that of the JSON string. In the first example, a list of Employee data has empName and empCode so it will convert fine, but in the second example you haven't catered for empId so it doesn't know how to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on status code you need different classes for deserialization. Use the following code to extract statusCode and deserialize string later to different object using your approach (Newtonsoft.json nuget is used):

```
dynamic js = JObject.Parse(str);
var code = js.statusCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("statusCode")]
    public long StatusCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Employee[] Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    [JsonProperty("empName")]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("empCode")]
    public long EmpCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("empId")]
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
}

var ResponseJSON= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(normalJson);
```

above class will help you to parse your json. you just need to check for Emplid is null or empty base on that you can simply do your work what you need.